# Adobe Forms records do not flow after first page

Tags: abap, adobe-form

I'm kinda stuck with a problem which I have no idea how to fix. I'm doing a nested loop using 2 tables in the form but the output is funny where the records disappear for records more than a page. It shows only one page but not the balance of it. Besides that, there is a blank page before the records as well. Please help me with this.

- if the child table has less than 72 records per item, then it's fine.

Thank you Gurus

Comment: ...and how are we supposed to reproduce this issue?

Comment: simply create an adobe form with nested table.for each parent item,assign 200 child items to it and see the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use Parallel Cursor for the nested loop and store all values in 1 Final Table.